# how to repaint a rotated rectangle area in java without affecting other components

Tags: java, awt, java-2d

i have created a 
rectangle by using 
GeneralPath class and 
rotated it using 
AffineTransform. And now 
i can't specify 
its coordinates or 
width and height in the 
repaint method without 
affecting other elements. 
please provide a solution.
A working example will be
much appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Please provide a runnable example which demonstrates your problem